# Overpass XML query with multiple polygons or bounding boxes

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I am having trouble creating an OpenStreeMap Overpass XML combined polygon/bounding box query to return what I want. Can someone provide a simple example or correct the following XML?

I want to construct a query to retrieve data from multiple polygons or bounding boxes. Specifically, I want to retrieve all data within a small polygon and only certain data types, major roads, in a larger containing bounding box and return the combined result.

This XML shows conceptually what I want to do but is returning all data for the larger area rather than all data for the small area and major roads for the larger area:

```
<osm-script timeout="20" element-limit="1073741824">
    <union into="_">
        <!-- Smaller area, all data -->
        <polygon-query into="_" bounds="54.12 -2.779  54.143 -2.779  54.143 -2.761 54.12 -2.761" />
        <recurse from="_" into="_" type="up"/>
        <recurse from="_" into="_" type="down"/>
    </union>      
    <union into="_">
        <!-- Larger area, major roads only -->
        <bbox-query s="54.12" n="54.143" w="-2.779" e="-2.744" />
        <has-kv k="highway" v="motorway"/>   
        <recurse from="_" into="_" type="up"/>
        <recurse from="_" into="_" type="down"/>
    </union>
    <print from="_" limit="" order="id"/>
</osm-script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have edited it to work, hope it is what you want

```
<osm-script timeout="20" element-limit="1073741824">
<union into="_">
    <!-- Smaller area, all data -->
    <query type="node">
      <polygon-query into="_" bounds="54.12 -2.779  54.143 -2.779  54.143 -2.761 54.12 -2.761" />
  </query>
  <query type="way">
      <polygon-query into="_" bounds="54.12 -2.779  54.143 -2.779  54.143 -2.761 54.12 -2.761" />
  </query><query type="relation">
      <polygon-query into="_" bounds="54.12 -2.779  54.143 -2.779  54.143 -2.761 54.12 -2.761" />
  </query>
    <recurse from="_" into="_" type="up"/>
    <recurse from="_" into="_" type="down"/>
  <query type="way">
    <bbox-query s="54.12" n="54.143" w="-2.779" e="-2.744" />
    <has-kv k="highway" v="motorway"/>   
    </query>
    <recurse from="_" into="_" type="up"/>
    <recurse from="_" into="_" type="down"/>
</union>
<print from="_" limit="" order="id"/>
```

Comment: Thank you, that answers the question by helping me understand the logic much better so I am accepting it as the answer.  I found that not all the data I expected mapped out. This appeared mostly due to missing nodes so I added the two recursion statements after each and every query, (not sure why that is necessary), and, for the motorways, had to add `<recurse type="way-node"/>`.  In more complex examples this now giving more than I want in the outer area as it also bring in ways that share the same nodes, but nearly there.